# RecoverySystem.installPackage - /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCESS (permission denied) - missing permission after update Android to 4.3+

Tags: android, permissions

I already searched in the Internet an answer to my problem, but unfortunately I have not found a solution for my issue. I even wrote in this case on the [official forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers), Unfortunately, the moderators could not cope with this problem. Below I describe the problem, hoping that someone had a similar problem and knows the solution.

I made an application that works fine on Android 4.1, which is why I reject the problems associated with the lack of "something".
For now, it seems that in newer versions of android is a bug, because after updating to Android 4.3+ (API 18+) my app shows the message:

> /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCESS (permission denied)

My application is an system application, so the file `*.apk` was put in directory `/system/app/`
together with a suitable file access permissions (chmod), so that the `context.getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` is equal 1.

Because the application uses the method [`RecoverySystem.installPackage(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#installPackage%28android.content.Context,%20java.io.File%29) I added permissions:

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" />
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

More than the required minimum, because among others my application uses the method `RecoverySystem.verifyPackage(...)`
Also, this method had problems after updating to Android 4.3+, but these problems have been solved after adding one of (or all) permissions:

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />`

**NOTE:**
For testing I added to manifest file also all the possible permissions that are available, but this does not solve the problem.

Once again, I would like to emphasize that the application works correctly until an update to android 4.3+. 
After the update there is an error with the message:

> /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCESS (permission denied)

This error occurs when call the method `RecoverySystem.installPackage(...)`.
(`FileWriter command = new FileWriter(COMMAND_FILE);` where `COMMAND_FILE` == `/cache/recovery/command`)

I'm not sure, but I think that one of the possible reasons may be bug in the 'bootable/recovery/recovery.c', but I can not find any confirmation.

If anyone can help, I'd be grateful.

P.S. To avoid mess in the Internet, do not post with texts like "use Google", "already it was - I've seen it somewhere - but can not remember where", "I have the same problem / also not working for me", and other posts which do not help solve the problem.

---

@shiri-hrw Thanks for reply.

after adding **android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared"** to my apps manifest (AndroidManifest.xml), an error occurred:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE Please
>   check logcat output for more details.
>   Launch canceled!

**LogCat**

> Package com.example.test has no signatures that match those in shared user **com.google.uid.shared**; ignoring!

**and/or**

> Package com.example.test has no signatures that match those in shared user **android.uid.system**; ignoring!

You wrote:

> ...as your app isn't signed with google signatures...

but after sign application, using files *.pk8 and *.x509.pem, which can be found under build/target/product/security in the pulbic sdk.

`java -jar SignApk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8   Application.apk Application_signed.apk`

and/or

`java -jar SignApk.jar shared.x509.pem shared.pk8   Application.apk Application_signed.apk`

the error still occurs.

When I push my app to **system/app** (and reboot) the application is not visible in apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, but solved it.
If you  firmware is 4.3+ then, 
You should add `android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared"` in you apps manifest, and push your app to **system/app**.

For this you can root your device
But after adding this, your will not get installed, as during installation  verifySignaturesLP method from PackageManagerService will return false as your app isn't signed with google signatures, so you have to make changes in that method to check you apps package and return true there.

You are getting that error because your app have not signatures matching to those of Google. Though you have signed your app using *.pk, but that/those file/s doesn't contain signature that Google uses to sign their app.

So to install your app, you need to modify your framework code as I mentioned previously.
e.g. you can modify your `verifySignaturesLP` method to return true for your application.

***Or second option***
If you are not able to do so, then I'm not sure, but you can try another thing.
Instead of using that shared id use, shared id of other system applications in your device.
e.g. I used `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` 
Then make your device permissive by giving below commands

```
1. adb shell
2. setenforce 0
```

Remember you should get *Permissive* instead of *Enforcing* for `getenforce` after above commands. And then try. I'm not 100% sure about this second option.
Hope this second option works in your case.

Comment: I gave answers, editing my question. Have you any idea how to solve this?

Comment: check I have modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use KitKat (4.4), then put your apk in /system/priv-app instead of /system/app.

Comment: what about untrusted_app?